# Handling null values with join across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My mind is exploding right now.. I can't get any of this to work the way I want to! SQL is seriously such a pain in the butt. (/End Rant)

I have three tables that have some common columns to link with. I am trying to retrieve the ID off one table based on the name from the middle table based on the code from the farthest table. (Excuse my vocabulary, I am not skilled with SQL or its' lingo) If the farthest table has a code not found in the middle table, it is to default to a certain value. Then, the first table will return the default for null values. etc.

Example,

- `tblCounty` table has an `ID` and `name` column. I am to return the `ID` from `tblCounty` based on the `name` column matching the `name` column of `tblCode`.
- `tblCode` has two columns `name` and `code`. `tblCode` returns the respective `name` based on the matching `code` column with `tblAddress`'s `code` column.
- `tblAdress` has many columns, but shares in common a code field.

My attempt,

```
INSERT INTO vendor (CountyID, Contact)
  SELECT 
     (SELECT a.id 
      FROM county a 
      WHERE a.name = (CASE WHEN (SELECT TOP(1) c.countyID 
                                 FROM tblAdress c 
                                 INNER JOIN tblCode d ON c.CountyID = d.CodeID 
                                 WHERE d.CodeID = b.CountyID) IS NULL THEN '**NONE**' 
                           ELSE (SELECT a.CodeName 
                                 FROM tblCode a 
                                 WHERE a.CodeID = b.CountyID) END)),
     b.Contact
  FROM 
     tblAdress b
```

The error I am receiving is:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Now of course I googled this and looked at results on StackOverflow, but I was unable to apply what I found to my problem.

**Vendor**:

```
CountyID  |  .... 
-------------------
1         | ... 
2         | ... 
3         | ... 
2         | ...
```

**tblCounty**:

```
ID   |   Name  | ...
----------------------
1    | **None** 
2    |  NYC 
3    |  Buffalo
```

**tblCode**:

```
 Name     |  Code
 --------------
 **None** |  **None** 
 NYC      |    56A 
 Buffalo  |    75B
```

**tblAdress**:

```
Code     |  ....
----------------
**None** |  .... 
56A      | ...... 
75B      | ..... 
56A      | .....
```

Using the above tables, I want to transfer all data out of `tblAdress` into another table (`vendor`). In the process I will convert column `Code` to `tblCode`'s column `name` via `code` comparison, then to `tblCounty.ID` via `name` comparison.

**Essentially a catch all is needed.** If a code in `tblAddress` does not exist in `tblCode` or the code is null in `tblAddress`, it will return a default value (`None`). Then `tblCounty` will convert that default value into `ID = 1`, then store it into the `Vendor` table.

**Edit**

```
(SELECT TOP(1)
        c.ID
FROM 
        dbo.Address a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.tblCode cd ON ISNULL(CASE a.CountyID WHEN ' ' THEN '**None**' ELSE a.CountyID END, '**None**') = cd.CodeID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.tblCounty c ON c.NAME = cd.CodeName
WHERE a.CountyID = b.countyID)
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desire output.

Comment: @lily please stop making stupid edits.

Comment: Added tables with some example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your database doesn't seem to be following the best practices of creating a database.

Ideally the design of the relationships and tables should prevent you having to do null checks in joins and the majority of the time a simple left join would do most of what you want. Could you can use constraints and ISNULLs when the data is being added to ensure its integrity? Also, I would advise against joining tables on text like county if you can - It would be much more elegant to use an integer primary key.

I suggest that you make sure that your design is solid before progressing, as these problems may just multiply in the future.

That being said, if you are insistent on continuing the way you're going, the following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT  tblCounty.ID, 
    ISNULL(tblAddress.Code, 'none')
    --Whatever you want to select
FROM tblCounty
LEFT JOIN tblCode ON tblCounty.Name = tblCode.Name
    LEFT JOIN tblAddres ON ISNULL(tblCode.Code, 'none') = ISNULL(tblAddress.Code, 'none')
```

Comment: This helped enough to lead me in the right direction. Thanks! 

Lets just say I am an intern tasked with converting/transferring this companies old database to a new database. The new database has many relationships and causing me grief because the old one has ZERO relationships with many inconsistencies in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Would this not get you the desired results?

```
select isnull(a.ID, '**NONE**') as CountyID, c.Contact
from tblCounty a
left join tblCode b on a.Name = b.Name
left join tblAddress c on b.Code = c.Code
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. I understand where you are going with this, but there are repeats in the data. So, in tblAddress's name field there will be repeats. The middle table ,tblCode, contains no repeats. Tried TOP(1), but this just returned the same ID all the way down :/

Comment: What about `select distinct (isnull...` ?

Comment: Applying distinct did not work. I am now managing to get "Cannot insert NULL into column". I did edit the question above with some more information, that might help?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so let's try to build this query:

- from `tblCounty`, you want the ID?
- `tblCounty` and `tblCode` are linked via the `name` column? (bad idea - opens all sorts of issues - I'd rather use `code` or something!)
- `tblAdress` is linked to `tblCode` via the `code` column

Right?

OK, so let's try this:

- if you want to "link" two tables that have a column in common, and you want only rows that exist in both tables - use an `INNER JOIN`
- if you want to "link" two tables that have a column in common, and you want all rows, even those that don't exist in the "right" table, use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

So I'd say you need something like this:

```
SELECT
   c.ID, c.Name, ...(whatever other columns you want),
   -- if there's no entry in `tblAddress`, then `a.Name` will be `NULL`
   -- so just replace that `NULL` with your default value
   ISNULL(a.Name, '*DEFAULT NAME*')
FROM
   dbo.tblCounty c
INNER JOIN
   dbo.tblCode cd ON c.Name = cd.Name
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.tblAddress a ON cd.Code = a.Code
```

**Update:** OK, so I tried with your sample data - how about this query?

```
SELECT
    c.ID, cd.Code, 
    a.StreetName
FROM 
    dbo.tblAdress a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.tblCode cd ON ISNULL(a.Code, 'None') = cd.COde
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.tblCounty c ON c.NAME = cd.NAME
```

Comment: Been trying to work with this, I have no success. either same error, or can not enter NULL. I did add more information to the question, that might help?

Comment: I was able to run this code once, and I seen a bunch of NULL values. I wanted to make sure it wasn't my temp data messing stuff up, so I went to delete it... Accidentally deleted all data! I'll be back tomorrow, with new data, to continue this.

Comment: I did some modification to handle blank spaces, but interestingly I am still getting cannot insert NULL values error. I will update code up top.